# An sql trigger isn't working properly when updating data in datagridview

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I am using trigger in order to update the status of a grade when a final or secondrun grade is updated, knowing that when i update a final grade using an update statement in sql management studio the status is changed while when i update a final grade from the application using datagridview the status isn't affected.
[datagridview of the table updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUgAL.png)
- p represents passed

- ip represents in progress
- f represents failed
  this is the trigger

  ```
  BEGIN
  DECLARE
  @SECONDRUN int, 
  @FINAL int,
  @MIDTERM int,
  @COURSE_ID int,
  @PassGrade int,
  @YR_ID DECIMAL(2,1),
  @status nvarchar(50)

  SELECT
  @SECONDRUN=SECONDRUN,
  @FINAL = FINAL,
  @MIDTERM = MIDTERM,
  @COURSE_ID = COURSE_ID,
  @PassGrade=PASS,
  @YR_ID = YR_ID,
  @status=[status]
  FROM INSERTED

  -- Insert statements for trigger here
  IF UPDATE(SECONDRUN)
  begin
  IF ISNULL (@SECONDRUN ,0)=0
  begin
  UPDATE REGISTRATION 
  SET registration.[STATUS] ='ip',
  LastModified =GETDATE ()
  FROM REGISTRATION
  join inserted I
  on REGISTRATION.PRKY = I.PRKY
  end
  ELSE if(@SECONDRUN>=@PassGrade)
  begin
  UPDATE REGISTRATION
  SET Registration.[STATUS] = 'p',
  lastmodified=getdate()
  FROM REGISTRATION
  join inserted I
  on REGISTRATION.PRKY = I.PRKY   
  end
  else if(@SECONDRUN<@PassGrade)
  begin
  UPDATE REGISTRATION
  SET Registration.[STATUS] = 'f',
  lastmodified=getdate()
  FROM REGISTRATION
  join inserted I
  on REGISTRATION.PRKY = I.PRKY   
  end                 

  end
  else  IF 
  UPDATE(FINAL) 
  begin 
  IF
  ISNULL (@FINAL ,0)=0
  UPDATE REGISTRATION 
  SET registration.[STATUS] ='ip',
  LastModified =GETDATE ()
  FROM REGISTRATION
  join inserted I
  on REGISTRATION.PRKY = I.PRKY
  ELSE if(@FINAL>=@PassGrade)
  begin
  UPDATE REGISTRATION
  SET Registration.[STATUS] = 'P',
  lastmodified=getdate()
  FROM REGISTRATION
  join inserted I
  on REGISTRATION.PRKY = I.PRKY   
  end
  else if(@FINAL<@PassGrade)
  begin
  UPDATE REGISTRATION
  SET Registration.[STATUS] = 'ip',
  lastmodified=getdate()
  FROM REGISTRATION
  join inserted I
  on REGISTRATION.PRKY = I.PRKY   
  end
  end 
  end
  ```

at the begining the column status wasn't in the selection sql statement in dataset ,then i add it, but there is no change in results.

Comment: Your trigger is broken, for reasons that may not be apparent to you yet - triggers fire once per *statement*, not once per *row*. `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. So your variable assignments are taking values from one of those rows and ignoring all others.

Comment: i noticed that the status is changing according to the first if , so if if (secondrun) is first, changes are done according to it, while if if(final) is put before if(secondrun) then status changes according to final.Also there sometimes multiple row are changed together.